# java.io.FileNotFoundException along with Gradle error while downloading artifacts

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am not quite sure if its the issue with **signing-config.json** file or the **gradle issue**  or perhaps both.

The test app i am working on was working perfectly till last night and when i tried to run the app again now it gives errors

**Error:**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on RNE L21 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\r\Desktop\exampleapp\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\r\Desktop\exampleapp\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

internet connection is stable, i didnt change any thing in the app from last night , so can someone point out what could be the reason for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make minSdkVersion 21 I hope this would be solution for your problem in app level build.gradel file

```
 minSdkVersion 21
```

Comment: i changed it but still the same issue ,and honestly i dont think changing it should make any difference because it was working last night with minsdkversion 23

Comment: are you try flutter clean